# Gradle Tasks show not full list

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

In Gradle folder I know there should be a lot more options inside Tasks, and they're not showing after reinstalling project.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add "Configure all Gradle tasks during Gradle Sync" in Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use Android Stuio Giraffe and this worked for me:

Go to
File -> Settings -> Experimental

Check the next option:

**Configure all Gradle tasks during Gardle Sync (this can make Gradle Sync slower)**

After that **sync gradle**:
File -> Sync project with Gradle file

[image]